# Convert CipherInputStream to FileInputStream

Tags: android, encryption, android-mediaplayer, android-file, nanohttpd

I am using nano-httpd to play encrypted mp3 file. I want to play encrypted file on the fly. I apply decryption AES-256 and send the CipherInputStream file to NanoHttpd but it throws exception. Actually it requires FileInputStream. Errors are stated below

```
return new NanoHTTPD.Response(Response.Status.OK, "audio/mpeg", CipherInputStreamFile); // here it requires FileInputStream File

**Exception**
D/MediaPlayer: Couldn't open file on client side, trying server side
E/MediaPlayer: error (1, -2147483648)
E/MediaPlayer: Error (1,-2147483648)
```